# How do I call services on my bookings form? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have clients page, services page and using a bookable gem. So currently when I click "Book" besides a customers name, a booking form pops up which allows me to choose a date and time and the length of the appointment. However, with this form I would like to also be able to choose the service that the appointment needs, so once a service has been added, a drop down list on the bookings form will show the services which have been added. (Hopefully that made sense)

Is there any chance someone could please help me with how I can do this?

**Bookings (_form.html.erb)**

```
<%= form_for([@client, @booking]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'start_time', 'Start time' %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :start_time, { minute_step: 15 } %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'length', 'Length of booking in hours' %>
    <%= f.number_field 'length', min: 1 %>
  </p>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

**Services (index.html.erb)**

```
<h1>Services <%= link_to "+ New", new_service_path %></h1>

<table>
<div class="row">
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3">
    <h3>Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3">
    <h3>Description</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3">
    <h3>Price</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3">
    <h3>Service Duration</h3>
  </div>
</div>

  <tbody>
    <% @services.each do |service| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= service.name %></td>
        <td class="tb1"><%= service.description %></td>
        <td class="tb2"><%= service.price %></td>
        <td class="tb3"><%= service.duration %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', service %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_service_path(service) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', service, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  before_action :find_client

  def index
    @bookings = Booking.where("client_id = ? AND end_time >= ?", @client.id, Time.now).order(:start_time)
    respond_with @bookings
  end

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new(client_id: @client.id)
  end

  def create
    @booking =  Booking.new(params[:booking].permit(:client_id, :start_time, :length))
    @booking.client = @client
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to client_bookings_path(@client, method: :get)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id]).destroy
    if @booking.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Booking: #{@booking.start_time.strftime('%e %b %Y %H:%M%p')} to #{@booking.end_time.strftime('%e %b %Y %H:%M%p')} deleted"
      redirect_to client_bookings_path(@client)
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    # @booking.clients = @clients

    if @booking.update(params[:booking].permit(:client_id, :start_time, :length))
      flash[:notice] = 'Your booking was updated succesfully'

      if request.xhr?
        render json: {status: :success}.to_json
      else
        redirect_to client_bookings_path(@client)
      end
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def save booking
    if @booking.save
        flash[:notice] = 'booking added'
        redirect_to client_booking_path(@client, @booking)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def find_client
    if params[:client_id]
      @client = Client.find_by_id(params[:client_id])
    end
  end
end
```

**services_controller.rb**

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_service, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /services
  # GET /services.json
  def index
    @services = Service.all
  end

  # GET /services/1
  # GET /services/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /services/new
  def new
    @service = Service.new
  end

  # GET /services/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /services
  # POST /services.json
  def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /services/1
  # PATCH/PUT /services/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.update(service_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /services/1
  # DELETE /services/1.json
  def destroy
    @service.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to services_url, notice: 'Service was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_service
      @service = Service.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def service_params
      params.require(:service).permit(:name, :description, :price, :duration)
    end
end
```

Comment: This is a JS issue. Based on an input value, you can easily populate other form values.

Comment: You probably want `accepts_nested_attributes_for` have a look at https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as i can tell, what you want is on the bookings form (ie the new action) you'd like to display a drop-down that has all of the services so it can be chosen. Then when they submit this, they add that service to their booking?

Well, firstly - you'd need to add `service_id` as a column to your bookings table and the association in the `Booking` class.
I'd recommend using the specialised migration for associations: `references` eg:

```
class AddServiceToBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :bookings, :service, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

It's a good idea to then add the association to your booking class:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
```

Then you can show the collection of services in the service-drop-down in the form using [collection_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select):

```
<%= form_for([@client, @booking]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'start_time', 'Start time' %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :start_time, { minute_step: 15 } %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'length', 'Length of booking in hours' %>
    <%= f.number_field 'length', min: 1 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'service_id', 'Service' %>
    <%= f.collection_select :service_id, Service.all, :id, :name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Then you'll need to allow the `service_id` in your permit/require section of your bookings controller:

```
@booking =  Booking.new(params[:booking].permit(:client_id, :service_id, :start_time, :length))
```

And you might need some more tweaking here and there, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I tried this some time back and it worked perfectly fine!! Taryn, you're amazing. Once again thanks! :)